# do not create meta-inf/maven in jar package when using maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have one project that using maven assembly plugin for merging two jar,without using maven assembly ,create jar package  have meta-inf/maven that contain pom.properties and pom.xml .  but after merge by Assembly this folder not exists.

i search it and found that this can make that OK but dose not work .

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/frm-assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <archive>
             **<addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>**
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and descriptor is this

```
<assembly>
    <id>uberjar</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/META-INF/resources</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: the `addMavenDescriptor` is already at `true` by default, that's why it didn't change much, the change is required somewhere else. So you claim that the jar generated by the `assembly` plugin doesn't provide descriptors?

Comment: yes do not create descriptors like pom.xml and pom.properties